# Cloning assosiations with attached file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clone, attachment

I have got an object wich I am using as a pattern. This objects has got a number of associations. One of those association is an attach. My object has many attaches. I can clone all, you know, db data, but how should I do it with files, that are attached to my object.

I can imagine some solutions, but all of them little hacky and don't look native.

For example I can add virtual attribute to temprorary store ids of attaches while I am cloning an object.

Answer (score 1):

what's the solution do you have to manage attachments? If something like Paperclip, it has a callback that handles remove/cloning the real files on filesystem level.

Comment: The problem is: while I am cloning a model I need to show its form. So if I clone file, I should somehow remove it if form won't be accepted.